# Laravel form data redirect to error when try to save on DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have created registration form using Laravel, Form is working well, Validations are also working well but **without validation error, when I try to save data, it redirects to "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."** can someone please help me to find this error. thank you.

**Form:**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>"create-account")) }}
<p>
    {{ Form::text('user_name', '', array('placeholder'=>"User Name")) }}
    @if($errors->has('user_name'))
        <label> {{  $errors->first('user_name') }} </label>
    @endif
</p> 
<p>
    {{ Form::text('user_email', '', array('placeholder'=>"User Email")) }}
    @if($errors->has('user_email'))
        {{ $errors->first('user_email') }}
    @endif
</p>
<p>
    {{ Form::password('user_password', array('placeholder'=>"User Password")) }}
    @if($errors->has('user_password'))
        {{ $errors->first('user_password') }}
    @endif
</p> 
<p>{{ Form::submit('Register') }}</p>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**And Controller has this code:**

```
class StaffController extends BaseController {

    public function getAccount() {
        return View::make('staff.account');
    }

    public function postAccount() {
        $input = Input::all();
        $rules = array(
            'user_name' => 'required|min:3|max:20|unique:users',
            'user_email' => 'required|email|max:50|unique:users',
            'user_password' => 'required|min:5'
        );
        $validate = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        if ($validate->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('create-account')
                            ->withErrors($validate);
        } else {
                $user = new User();
                $user->user_name = $input['user_name'];
                $user->user_email = $input['user_email'];
                $user->user_password = Hash::make($input['user_password']);
                $user->save();
                return Redirect::to('login')
                        ->with('global', 'Your account has been created, please login'); 
        }
    }

}
```

**Model:**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    //protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
        protected $hidden = array('user_password');

}
```

**DB table has fields:**

Table name: users
Fields: 
user_id int(11)
user_name   varchar(20)
user_email  varchar(50)
user_password   varchar(60)
status

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@getIndex');
Route::get('login','HomeController@getIndex');
Route::post('login','HomeController@postLogin');
Route::get('create-account', 'StaffController@getAccount');
Route::post('create-account', 'StaffController@postAccount');
```

Comment: please enable debug output in your app/config/app.php: `'debug' => true,`.. also check if the user is created before laravel throws an exception

Comment: @John Thank you I enabled it now, I got this msg:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`user_name`, `user_email`, `user_password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (mark, mark@gmail.com, y$zl.ApDt6hBrrgL04Luera.nFCDi.hmSvbx6mGv0k/YEJ3yGXvDsQy, 2014-10-08 12:16:22, 2014-10-08 12:16:22))

Comment: try adding this in the User Model: `public static $timestamps = false;`

Comment: Or create the `created_at` & `updated_at` fields for your model in a migration or similar.